# mousePressEvent called only from certain areas in scene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have an application which draws lines based on different data from cars. I want my application to be able to select the lines drawn, and then make the corresponding item selected in a list on the left as well. The problem is that the mousePressEvent is only called when I press the mousebutton in the leftmost quarter of the scene. When it is called the curveSelected() function works as well, but I can't figure out why I can't invoke the mousePressEvent from the other areas on the scene.

First of all I have a mousePressEvent.

```
void DrawingScene:::mousePressEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event ){
    event->ignore();
    bool leftbutton = (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton);
    if(leftbutton)
    {
     qDebug() << "leftbutton";
     emit leftButtonPress(event->scenePos());
    }
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Later connected:

```
connect(d_scene, SIGNAL(leftButtonPress(QPointF)), this, SLOT(curveSelected(QPointF)));
```

leftButtonPress is the signal emitted. Then I have the function which selects the item in the list. This method seems to work just fine. The problem exists without this function as well.

```
void CurveDrawer::curveSelected(QPointF pos){
QMapIterator<QPair<unitID, QString>, carData*> it(dataMap);
while(it.hasNext()){
    it.next();
    QPainterPath curPath = it.value()->pathItem->path();
    if(curPath.contains(pos)){
        for (int i = 0; i < list->count(); ++i) {
            QListWidgetItem* curItem = list->item(i);
            if(curItem == it.value()->listItem){
                qDebug() << "curveSelected";
                curItem->setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Anyone experienced something similar, or may see some obvious mistakes in my code?

EDIT:

How can i achieve that the mousePressEvent is called every time I click inside the scene? This is basically what I want it to do. Now it is only called when I click in certain area.

I tried to implement it with void DrawGraphicsView;;mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) now, and the same problem existed there. The event just got invoked from certain areas in the scene.

The strange thing for me is that when a certain place in the scene is in the left of the viewport it is not possible to invoke the mousepressEvent, but when I scroll the same place to the right in the viewport, then it is suddenly possible to invoke the mousepressEvent. Does this make the problem clearer?